# simple XML for python?

Tags: php, python, xml, lxml

i'm just trying to work out a simple way opening, editing and saving an xml file using python.

so far i have managed to open a file and write it to output.

i have not, however managed to print it out easily so that i know what's in any given object, traverse the object model, edit tags and attributes, or write the xml to a file.

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.parse('test.xml')

print etree.tostring(root);
```

i'm used to using simpleXML for php, which is a breeze.

please help, as i am finding the documentation difficult to comprehend :(

thanks :)

Comment: -1 That's not a question. A question goes something like "How do I [something specific]? I tried X, but Y didn't work/I got error message Z.". And FYI, lxml *is* the best and simplest XML library for Python. I really don't know what answers you expect...

Comment: i was hoping either for a quick & easy explanation for how to do this using xml, or a better alternative. simpleXML in php simply treats the dom like an object (which is what beautifulsoup seems to do too). however i can't find a simple way of opening, editing and saving an xml file despite a good attempt at the lxml docs. sorry the question isn't more specific!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lxml tutorial is nice and easy to understand. Check it out [here](http://codespeak.net/lxml/tutorial.html) and give it a try. It takes some time to used to, but as with everything, the initial steps are difficult.

Another excellent tutorial (and reference) I recommend is the tutorial by [John Shipman](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pylxml/). You should seriously give it a read.

I recommend: Read the tutorial and the book by Shipman. Then try out parsing simple XML files.

lxml is worth learning. Once you do learn it, you will love it. PS: All that I said is based on my personal experience.

EDIT: Based on your comment, you should use [this](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html) instead of lxml then. [Here](http://www.boddie.org.uk/python/XML_intro.html) is an easy to understand tutorial.

Comment: DOM in general is very unwieldy, the Python implementation in comparision to the ElementTree implementations doubly so...

Comment: @delnan: I suggested lxml but he seems aversive to it.

Comment: And yes, lxml is far far easier. That I agree.

Comment: is there an easy way to a) change specific nodes without using explicit parent/child relationships, and b) write 'root' from my example to a local xml file? that would be enough for me to jump on the lxml bandwagon! i'm happily using it to run xpath & parse html so am not completely averse to it! :)

Comment: @significance: Follow the tutorial I gave you and you can easily do this within an hour.

Comment: ok - fair enough - i will give that a go & post up some more specific questions if i can't fathom it. thanks.

Comment: tbh this is pretty much the answer i listend to, although amara is probably the literal answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to [Amara](http://www.xml3k.org/Amara), it's very simple:

```
import amara
doc = amara.parse('monty.xml')
doc.monty.foo = u'bar'
doc.monty.spam = u'[attr modified]'
print doc.monty.foo
```

Comment: this actually might be what i'm looking for... do you know how to write the amended xml back to monty.xml?

Comment: doc.xml(open('monty.xml', 'w'))

Answer (score 1):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is very easy to use, and has a variant ([BeautifulStoneSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Parsing%20XML)) for plain ol' XML.

Answer (score 0):

I just found SimpleXML for Python: https://github.com/joestump/python-simplexml

Its really cool, just started using it and it works like SimpleXML for PHP.